# IApplicationBuilder dos not contain a definition UseEndpoints. app.UseEndpoints(...) not workin on ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, netcoreapp2.1

I'm trying to incorporate signalR on my project, but when I try to use app.UseEndpoints(...) it gives me an error saying that "IApplicationBuilder does not contain UserEndpoints. Here is the code on my StartUp class:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        //SIGNAL R - ERROR
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/myHub");
        });



        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

What should I do?

My Hub:

```
 public class MyHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
   {
    public async Task PostMarker(string latitude, string longitude) 
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveLocation", latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: In the csproj file of your project, what does it say for `<TargetFramework>...</TargetFramework>`

Comment: it says netcoreapp2.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per your comment, you are targeting .NET Core 2.1, but [the `UseEndpoints` extension method was introduced in 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure).

To add SignalR in 2.1, firstly make sure you have `services.AddSignalR();` in your `ConfigureServices` method. Secondly, you should use `app.UseSignalR` in the `Configure` method, instead of `UseEndpoints`.

Like so:

```
app.UseSignalR(route =>
{
    route.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
});
```

Comment: It kind of worked, howerver now I have an error on MapHub<ChatHub> saying that ChatHub cannot be used as type parameter 'THub'

Comment: Have you defined ChatHub to be a Hub? Take a look at [this tutorial from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.1), it should help you.

Comment: Yes, I have it as Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub. It doesn't let me use it as just Hub even if I put the using in the begining. Does that influence the error?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the definition of your hub

Comment: I've update my answer as per your edit. In your original code you called your hub ChatHub, so I assumed you have a hub called ChatHub. But it looks like your hub is called `MyHub`. So it should be `route.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");`

Comment: I realized that error, I already fix it, but the other one is MapHub<MyHub> it's still having an error

Comment: Did you try taking a look at the tutorial link I shared?